# Plotting a 3D sphere i.e. how to vizualise the spanned volume $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} d\theta d\phi$?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to help this guy [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188490/5902) to vizualise the integration volume. How can I plot the different integrals ie a ball and the ball adjusted by a trigonometric function?

**Integrals needing visual cue: what does their spanned volume look like?**

> He was wondering why the first integral is not spherical. I want to provide some sort of visual cue in this kind of issues.
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} d\theta d\phi = 2 \pi^2$$
>
> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta d\theta d\phi = 4 \pi$$

Comment: Have you read the help page for `SphericalPlot3D`?

Comment: The easiest way to plot a sphere is `Graphics3D[Sphere[]]`.  Are you wishing to parametrize the surface with spherical coordinates?

Comment: Can I do some of the commands with WolframAlpha? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=++SphericalPlot3D%28%7B1%7D%2C%7B%5Ctheta%2C0%2C2%5Cpi%7D%2C%7B%5Crho%2C-%5Cpi%2F2%2C%5Cpi%2F2%7D%29

Comment: @MichaelE2 I try to help the guy by visualizing different volumes by slightly changing parametrization, last sentence.

Comment: Perhaps this [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SurfaceParametrizationsAndTheirJacobians/) would help.

Comment: Ok, someone had to say this and it might as well be me:  Not only did you use MATLAB code for the example, you gave an _incorrect_ example that generated an arbitrary plot and wanted us to provide an explanation as to why your MATLAB plot fails. On top of this, you just toss in a casual "eh, it's similar to _Mathematica_ so fix my MATLAB code" in the hopes that it'll fly here... Please, if you need help with MATLAB, ask at [so]. If you want to ask help here, then please show effort in _Mathematica_ (or at least show fully working code in language X with your best attempt at translating it).

Comment: @Hypnotoad thank you, moved the matlab question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227914/why-not-spherical-plot-how-to-plot-3d-polar-plot-in-matlab). I did not know that I could ask matlab questions on a site, thank you for the info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very basic demonstration:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[theta] Cos[phi], 
   Sin[theta] Sin[phi], Cos[theta]},
  {theta, 0, t}, {phi, 0, p},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {t, 0.1, Pi}, {p, 0.1, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's another demonstration ([CDF](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/87514996/SphericalCoordinates.cdf), v9 but works with lower versions) I use in class:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{P0 = ρ (Sin[ϕ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[ϕ]}),
 $θColor = Red, $ϕColor = Darker[Blue], $ρColor = Brown},
  Graphics3D[{
    {PointSize[Medium], Point[P0], 
     Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #} & /@ (3 IdentityMatrix[3])], Opacity[0.3], 
     Line[{{0, 0, 0}, #} & /@ (-3 IdentityMatrix[3])]}, {
     {Opacity[0.3], 
      EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[Medium], Opacity[0.3]]], 
      Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, P0, {P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}}], $θColor,
       EdgeForm[
       Directive[Thickness[Medium], 
        If[Δρ == 0 && Δϕ == 0 && Δθ == 0, Opacity[1],
       Opacity[0.3]], $θColor]], 
      Polygon[Append[
        Table[0.3 {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 
          Append[Range[0, θ, 0.05], θ]}], {0, 0, 
         0}]], $ϕColor, 
      EdgeForm[
       Directive[Thickness[Medium], 
        If[Δρ == 0 && Δϕ == 0 && Δθ == 0,
       Opacity[1], Opacity[0.3]], $ϕColor]], 
      Polygon[Append[
        Table[0.5 (Sin[t] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0} + {0, 0, 
             Cos[t]}), {t, 
          Append[Range[0, ϕ, 0.05], ϕ]}], {0, 0, 0}]]},
     Line[{{P0, {0, 0, P0[[3]]}}, {{P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}, {P0[[1]], 0,
          0}}, {{P0[[1]], P0[[2]], 0}, {0, P0[[2]], 0}}}], 
     Point[DiagonalMatrix[P0]]
     },
    Which[
     Δρ == 0 && Δϕ == 0 && Δθ == 0, 
      { Thick, $ρColor, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, P0}] },
     Δρ == 0 && Δϕ == 0(*&&Δθ>0*), {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[ρ (Sin[ϕ] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 
            0, Cos[ϕ]}), {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, $θColor]]
      },
     Δρ == 0 &&(*Δϕ>
      0&&*)Δθ == 0, {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[ρ (Sin[s] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 
             0} + {0, 0, 
            Cos[s]}), {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ}, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, $ϕColor]]
      },
     (*Δρ>
     0&&*)Δϕ == 0 && Δθ == 0, {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[
        r (Sin[ϕ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0} + {0, 0, 
            Cos[ϕ]}), {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, $ρColor]]
      },
     Δρ == 0(*&&Δϕ>
     0&&Δθ>0*), {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[ρ (Sin[s] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0,  Cos[s]}),
          {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ},
          {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighter[$ρColor]]]
      },
     (*Δρ>0&&Δϕ>
     0&&*)Δθ == 0, {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[ r (Sin[s] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[s]}),
         {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ},
         {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> Lighter[$θColor]]
      },
     (*Δρ>
     0&&*)Δϕ == 0(*&&Δθ>
     0*), {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[
        r (Sin[ϕ] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[ϕ]}),
        {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ},
        {t, θ, θ + Δθ},
        Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Lighter[$ϕColor]]
      },
     True(*Δρ>0&&Δϕ>
     0&&Δθ>0*), {
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[ρ (Sin[s] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[s]}),
           {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ},
           {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$ρColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
      First@
       ParametricPlot3D[
        r (Sin[s] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[s]}),
           {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ},
           {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$θColor], 
           Opacity[opacity]]], 
      First@ParametricPlot3D[
        r (Sin[ϕ] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[ϕ]}),
           {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ},
           {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$ϕColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
      First@ParametricPlot3D[(ρ + Δρ) (Sin[s] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[s]}),
           {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ},
           {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$ρColor], Opacity[opacity]]], 
      First@ParametricPlot3D[
        r (Sin[s] {Cos[θ + Δθ], 
             Sin[θ + Δθ], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[s]}),
           {s, ϕ, ϕ + Δϕ},
           {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$θColor], 
           Opacity[opacity]]], 
      First@ParametricPlot3D[
        r (Sin[ϕ + Δϕ] {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, Cos[ϕ + Δϕ]}),
           {r, ρ, ρ + Δρ},
           {t, θ, θ + Δθ}, Mesh -> None, 
        PlotStyle -> 
         Dynamic@Directive[Lighter[$ϕColor], Opacity[opacity]]]
      }
     ]
    },
   SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 2, Lighting -> "Neutral"
   ]],
 Row[{Control[{{ρ, 1}, 0, 2, ImageSize -> Small}], 
   Control[{Δρ, 0, 1, ImageSize -> Small}]}, 
  Spacer[1]],
 Row[{Control[{ϕ, 0, π, ImageSize -> Small}], 
   Control[{Δϕ, 0, π, ImageSize -> Small}]}, 
  Spacer[1]],
 Row[{Control[{θ, 0, 2 π, ImageSize -> Small}], 
   Control[{Δθ, 0, 2 π, 
     ImageSize -> Small}]}, Spacer[1]],
 {{opacity, 1}, 0, 1}, ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

[image]

I might add that the reason for submitting it was that it shows, if one moves the `ϕ` slider, that the surface area element $dS$ or volume element $dV$ decreases as `ϕ` moves toward 0, or $\pi$, which is in part what his question was about.

Comment: I got several `ParametricPlot3D::nlnum` and ``Visualization`Core`ParametricPlot3D::invfuncs`` errors when using it. It happens when all three `Δ*` values are set. Here's a case when this happens: `{opacity = 1, Δθ = 1, Δρ = 
  1, Δφ = 1, θ = 0, ρ = 1, φ = 0}`. I haven't looked through the code to see where or why this occurs, but it'll be quicker for you to find it

Comment: @Hypnotoad Thanks, but when I use your settings I get no messages.  Random moving generates no messages either.  Perhaps something global was defined in your session?

Comment: Clean session, I'm also getting errors same as Hypnotoad. Also, if this is used in any sort of teaching setting, I would advice cleaning it up to improve readability.

Comment: Same here. I get the errors as soon as I change any of the `Δ...`

Comment: Thanks everyone for checking it out.  Sorry that it's so long - I thought I could just paste an old thing.  @jVincent: By readability, do you mean the code, the output, or both?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I like the output, I meant the code. For one thing, you have a huge load of code dealing with special cases for plotting the volume, why not just put this into a single function like `buildVolume` that way both the graphics generation is easier to read, and the whole special case handling.

Comment: @jVincent Thanks for explaining. I can't remember exactly how I wrote it (over two years ago), but the output was to stand alone and not depend on any global symbols being defined. I know, `buildVolume` can be localized. The students don't see the code, only the output.  It's for a calculus class. I was trying to help the OP with the last line in his question. I didn't mean it to be an example program (sorry if that's bad form), but I did mean that it should work! It wasn't until I suspected the pasted code was corrupted that I could fix my answer.