# How to generate 3D spherical sector

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

I looked but haven't found an answer to this one: I'd like to create a region that represents a sector of a ball, bounded between radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, polar angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, and azimuthal angles $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$. There seems to be no built-in functionality to achieve this directly. Do I have to assemble the region from parametric surfaces representing the spherical parts of the boundary, and trapezoids for the plane parts?

Comment: Possibly this?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17466/4999

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sphericalSegment[{r1_, r2_}, {θ1_, θ2_}, {ϕ1_, ϕ2_}] := 
 Module[{plot, pts, surf, bdy},
  plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]},
    {θ, θ1, θ2}, {ϕ, ϕ1, ϕ2}, 
    Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black];
  pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity];
  surf = First@Cases[plot, Polygon[p_] :> p, Infinity];
  bdy = First@Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
  GraphicsComplex[
   Join[r1*pts, r2*pts],
   {EdgeForm[],
    Polygon[surf], Polygon[Reverse /@ surf + Length@pts],
    Polygon[Join[#, Reverse@# + Length@pts], 
       VertexNormals -> Cross[Subtract @@ pts[[#]], pts[[First@#]]]] & /@ 
     Partition[bdy, 2, 1, 1]},
   VertexNormals -> Join[-pts, pts]
   ]
  ]

Graphics3D[
 sphericalSegment[{0.95, 1.1}, {0, Pi/3}, {Pi/6, Pi/2}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks!

Comment: +1, but how did you know that you had to write `Reverse /@ surf` rather than just `surf`?

Comment: @C.E. (1) I've done it many times, so I do it without thinking. Sometimes I wonder if it's always necessary, but I do it anyway. (2) Polygons have an orientation (e.g. used by `FaceForm[]`). Reversing the points reverses the orientation.  Note the `VertexNormals` are reversed, too (negatives of each other).  I think if `r1 > r2`, you'll still get a good-looking segment, but with the notions of inside/outside reversed.

Comment: ok, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Great solution. Question: is there an easy way to modify this method to show the sector outline—that is, the edges between sector faces, but not every single constituent polygon edge?

Comment: @Adam Add at the end before the last `}` and after `Partition[bdy, 2, 1, 1]`: `{Black, Thick, Line[bdy], Line[bdy + Length@pts], Line[Transpose@{#, # + Length@pts} &@Flatten@Nearest[pts -> "Index", Flatten[Table[{Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}, {θ, {θ1, θ2}}, {ϕ, {ϕ1, ϕ2}}], 1]]]}`

Comment: @Michael E2, thanks so much! Works beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

Definition of the region:

```
reg := (r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r2^2 && (* conditions on radius *)
        θ1 <= ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] <=  θ2 && (* conditions on polar angle *)
        φ1 <= ArcTan[x, y] <= φ2 (* conditions on azimuthal angle *)
        );
```

Definition of the parameters:

```
{r1, r2, θ1, θ2, φ1, φ2} = {2, 2.2, 30°, 180°, 15°, 85°};
```

Plots:

```
RegionPlot3D[ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y, z}],
             PlotPoints -> 80, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> 20°]
```

[image: spherical sector]

```
RegionPlot3D[reg, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, {z, -2.5, 2.5}, Axes -> False, 
             PlotPoints -> 80, Boxed -> False, ViewAngle -> 20°, Mesh -> None]
```

[image: spherical sector]

Comment: Much more compact code, but `RegionPlot` is often somewhat "rough around the edges". I think there's a trick to get this to look better by going through `DiscretizedRegion` somehow. Too tired to look it up now, but that might work. Overall your code above is quite elegant, thanks!

Comment: @Pirx, you might want to see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486).

Comment: Ahah, very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The NURBS representation of a spherical sector is particularly convenient, and has the advantage of not having to carry too many `Polygon[]` objects:

```
sphericalSegment[{r1_, r2_}, {θ1_, θ2_}, {φ1_, φ2_}] /; r1 < r2 :=
         Module[{cknots = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, lknots = {0, 0, 1, 1},
                 θa = θ2 - θ1, φa = φ2 - φ1, a1, a2, cp, cθ, cφ, p1, p2, ws, wθ, wφ},
                cθ = Cos[θa/2]; cφ = Cos[φa/2];
                a1 = {Cos[θ1], Sin[θ1]}; a2 = {Cos[θ2], Sin[θ2]};
                p1 = {Sin[φ1] , Cos[φ1]}; p2 = {Sin[φ2], Cos[φ2]};
                cp = Map[Function[pt, Append[#1 pt, #2]],
                         {a1, Normalize[(a1 + a2)/2]/cθ, a2}] & @@@
                     {p1, Normalize[(p1 + p2)/2]/cφ, p2};
                ws = Outer[Times, {1, cφ, 1}, {1, cθ, 1}];
                wθ = Outer[Times, {1, 1}, {1, cθ, 1}];
                wφ = Outer[Times, {1, 1}, {1, cφ, 1}];
                {BSplineSurface[r1 Reverse[cp, 2], SplineDegree -> 2,
                                SplineKnots -> {cknots, cknots}, SplineWeights -> ws],
                 BSplineSurface[Outer[Times, {r1, r2}, cp[[1]], 1], SplineDegree -> {1, 2},
                                SplineKnots -> {lknots, cknots}, SplineWeights -> wθ],
                 BSplineSurface[Outer[Times, {r1, r2}, Reverse[cp[[All, 1]]], 1],
                                SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, SplineKnots -> {lknots, cknots},
                                SplineWeights -> wφ], 
                 BSplineSurface[Outer[Times, {r1, r2}, cp[[All, -1]], 1],
                                SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, SplineKnots -> {lknots, cknots},
                                SplineWeights -> wφ],
                 BSplineSurface[Outer[Times, {r1, r2}, Reverse[cp[[-1]]], 1],
                                SplineDegree -> {1, 2}, SplineKnots -> {lknots, cknots},
                                SplineWeights -> wθ],
                 BSplineSurface[r2 cp, SplineDegree -> 2,
                                SplineKnots -> {cknots, cknots}, SplineWeights -> ws]}]
```

Some examples:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], sphericalSegment[{9/10, 1}, {0, π/3}, {π/6, π/2}]}]
```

[image: a spherical segment]

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], sphericalSegment[{9/10, 1}, {π/3, 3 π/4}, {π/2, π}]}]
```

[image: another spherical segment]

Comment: P. S. If needed, one can add `BaseStyle -> {BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 40}}}`, similar to what was done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25048).

Comment: Can this be used to generate arbitrary spherical polygon for given vertices? (I just don't have time to investigate :)) If you want I will ask an official question.

Comment: @Kuba, no, this is only good for making spherical quadrilaterals, or isosceles spherical triangles. Making an arbitrary spherical polygon with NURBS looks tough, from what I've researched.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pity. Does the fact that I don't care about very precise approximation changes anything?

Comment: @Kuba, you might want to look at [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78705) in the meantime; someday, when I find time, I'll try implementing the NURBS method for spherical polygons.

Comment: Yep, been there. Unless I missed something the performance presented there does not fit my needs. I'd rather go with `ClipPlanes` which can be applied as a directive for e.g. `Sphere[]`, the problem is to get the proper order of points in `InfinitePlane` and the fact the number of clipping planes is hardware dependent.