# Eigenvalues of 3D Laplacian on a spherical segment

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, finite-difference-method

To study the change in Laplacian eigenvalues on a spherical segment, I constructed a table of spherical segments using the code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126075/how-to-generate-3d-spherical-sector).

I discretized the output using `DiscretizeGraphics` and obtained a table of discretized spherical segments.[image].

As I try to apply `NDEigensystems` on the discretized figures, I get the following error:

[image]   [image]

The code I am using to generate the spherical segments :

```
sphericalSegment[{r1_,r2_}, {\[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_}, {\[Phi]1_, \[Phi]2_}]:=
Module[{plot, pts, surf, bdy},plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]],Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]],Cos[\[Phi]]}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]1, \[Theta]2}, {\[Phi], \\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black];
pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity];
surf = First@Cases[plot, Polygon[p_] :> p, Infinity];
bdy = First@Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
GraphicsComplex[Join[r1*pts, r2*pts], {EdgeForm[], Polygon[surf],  Polygon[Reverse /@ surf + Length@pts],Polygon[Join[#, Reverse@# + Length@pts], VertexNormals -> Cross[Subtract @@ pts[[#]], pts[[First@#]]]] & /@   Partition[bdy, 2, 1, 1]}, VertexNormals -> Join[-pts, pts]]]
```

Code to calculate the Laplacian Eigenvalues :

```
r = Flatten[Table[{Graphics3D[sphericalSegment[{1, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}, {Pi/n, Pi}]]}, {n, 1.2, 3, 0.2}]];
dr = DiscretizeGraphics /@ r;
eigs = NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + NeumannValue[0,True]}, f[x, y, z], Element[{x, y, z}, #],1] & /@ dr
```

Answer (score 2):

The missing text is

```
NDEigensystem::femnfm: The current version of NDSolve cannot solve equations over boundaries or surfaces. Please specify a region where the embedding dimension is the same as the dimension.
```

So your shells need some thickness.

Comment: off topic question, could `EmptyRegion[2]` typeset to `{}` inside `Graphics`? do you think it is a reasonable request?

Comment: @Kuba, Where does this come up? My thinking is that `EmptyRegion` is not a graphics primitive. You would not expect `Graphics[{Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]]}]` to work either. Can you show me an example where this is useful?

Comment: Everywhere where one wants to quickly show region based computation. e.g. [147287](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147287/5478) it would be nice to avoid `_EmptyRegion -> Nothing`. Or in recent [147708](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147708/5478)

Comment: The problem I have is probably that `RegionInstersection` of graphics primitives is not a graphics primitive, in case of EmptyRegion.

Comment: I see, the problem is that making `EmptyRegion` a graphics primitive would open the argument that every expr should be displayable by Graphics. I'd just use something like `ri = RegionIntersection[{Line[{l11, l12}], Line[{l21, l22}]}]; If[Head[ri] === EmptyRegion, {}, ri]` But why don't you send a suggestion to support?

Comment: I wanted to ask you first to check if that makes sense, I'm not using regions on daily basis.