# Drawing the intersection point of two dynamic lines

Tags: dynamic, geometry, intersection

I want to find the intersection point of two line segments determined by the position of four locators.

```
l11 = {0, 0};
l12 = {4, 4};
l21 = {0, 4};
l22 = {4, 0};
l1 = Line[{Dynamic[l11], Dynamic[l12]}];
l2 = Line[{Dynamic[l21], Dynamic[l22]}];
Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic[l11]],
                   l1,
                    Locator[Dynamic[l12]],
                    Locator[Dynamic[l21]],
                    l2,
                    Locator[Dynamic[l22]],
                    PointSize[3], RegionIntersection[{l1, l2}]},
 PlotRange -> 10, Axes -> True]
```

Mathematica gives an error:

> Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 4}}] is not a correctly specified region

As far as I understood, the error is caused by my `Line` expressions containing `Dynamic` expressions.

How can I fix my code to show the intersection of two such line segments?

Comment: I'd say it is a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/5478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your code by rewriting it only in terms of the four points where the locators are positioned.

```
DynamicModule[{l11 = {0., 0.}, l12 = {4., 4.}, l21 = {0., 4.}, l22 = {4., 0.}},
  Dynamic @
    Graphics[
      {Locator[Dynamic[l11]], Line[{l11, l12}], Locator[Dynamic[l12]],
       Locator[Dynamic[l21]], Line[{l21, l22}], Locator[Dynamic[l22]],
       Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
       RegionIntersection[{Line[{l11, l12}], Line[{l21, l22}]}]},
   PlotRange -> 10,
   Axes -> True]]
```

[image: intersect]