# How to plot this solid nicely?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the following solid nicely.

$\{(\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi,\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi,\rho\cos\phi)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid(\rho,\phi,\theta)\in[1,2]\times[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\times[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\}$.

The following code didn't work:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t] Sin[s], r Sin[t] Sin[s], r Cos[s]}, {r, 1, 2}, {s, 0, Pi/2}, {t, 0, Pi/2},ImageSize->Large, PlotStyle->Blue]
```

Please tell me how to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126075/how-to-generate-3d-spherical-sector/126077#12607 (`Graphics3D[sphericalSegment[{1, 2}, {0, Pi/2}, {0, Pi/2}]]`) --
Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17464/plotting-a-3d-sphere-i-e-how-to-vizualise-the-spanned-volume-int-02-pi-int/17466#17466

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Table[{r Cos[t] Sin[s], r Sin[t] Sin[s], r Cos[s]}, {r, 1, 2, .02}] //
   Evaluate, {s, 0, Pi/2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

**Another Way**

If we use the implicit expression of sphere, we can also construct the solids and it's complement by a relatively complex way.

```
SetOptions[ContourPlot3D, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Lighting -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}];
f1 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1^2;
f2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2^2;
f3 = x;
f4 = y;
f5 = z;
pureFun[f_] := (Evaluate[
     f /. {x -> Slot@1, y -> Slot@2, z -> Slot@3}]) &;
s1 = ContourPlot3D[f1 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f3, f4, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
       StippleShading[0.9]}, {None, None}}}, MeshStyle -> None];
s2 = ContourPlot3D[f2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f3, f4, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
       HatchShading[]}, {None, None}}}, MeshStyle -> None];
s3 = ContourPlot3D[f3 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f1, f2, f4, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}}, {{{None, 
        HalftoneShading[0.6, Orange]}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}}}, MeshStyle -> None];
s4 = ContourPlot3D[f4 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f1, f2, f3, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}}, {{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        HalftoneShading[0.6, Orange]}, {None, None}}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> None];
s5 = ContourPlot3D[f5 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        HalftoneShading[0.8, Orange]}, {None, None}}}, {{{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}, {{None, None}, {None, None}}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> None];
Show[s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**The Complement**

```
SetOptions[ContourPlot3D, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Lighting -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}, {0}}];
f1 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1^2;
f2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2^2;
f3 = x;
f4 = y;
f5 = z;
pureFun[f_] := (Evaluate[
     f /. {x -> Slot@1, y -> Slot@2, z -> Slot@3}]) &;
s1 = ContourPlot3D[f1 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f3, f4, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
       StippleShading[0.9]}, {None, None}}}, MeshStyle -> None];
s2 = ContourPlot3D[f2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f3, f4, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{HatchShading[], HatchShading[]}, {HatchShading[],
        HatchShading[]}}, {{HatchShading[], None}, {HatchShading[], 
       HatchShading[]}}}, MeshStyle -> None];
s3 = ContourPlot3D[f3 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f1, f2, f4, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}}, {{{None, 
        HalftoneShading[0.6, Orange]}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}}}, MeshStyle -> None];
s4 = ContourPlot3D[f4 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f1, f2, f3, f5}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}}, {{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        HalftoneShading[0.6, Orange]}, {None, None}}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> None];
s5 = ContourPlot3D[f5 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> pureFun /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}, 
   MeshShading -> {{{{None, None}, {None, None}}, {{None, 
        HalftoneShading[0.8, Orange]}, {None, None}}}, {{{None, 
        None}, {None, None}}, {{None, None}, {None, None}}}}, 
   MeshStyle -> None];
Show[s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: cvgmt, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the solid you can also use

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot3D[
   Table[{r Cos[t] Sin[s], r Sin[t] Sin[s], r Cos[s]}, {r, {1, 2}}], {s, 0, 
    Pi/2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, ImageSize -> Large];

pp2 = ParametricPlot3D[
   Table[{r Cos[t] Sin[s], r Sin[t] Sin[s], r Cos[s]}, {s, {0, Pi/2}}], {r, 1,
     2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, ImageSize -> Large];

pp3 = ParametricPlot3D[
   Table[{r Cos[t] Sin[s], r Sin[t] Sin[s], r Cos[s]}, {t, {0, Pi/2}}], {r, 1,
     2}, {s, 0, Pi/2}, ImageSize -> Large];

Show[pp1, pp2, pp3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SphericalShell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalShell.html) with `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[RegionIntersection[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}], 
   SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2}]], 
  Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[Region@SphericalShell[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, Axes -> True, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

> ```
> same picture
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html):

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[{1 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0}, {x, y, z}]

RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 80, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From [How to generate 3D spherical sector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126075/how-to-generate-3d-spherical-sector/126077#12607) :

```
sphericalSegment[{r1_, 
   r2_}, {θ1_, θ2_}, {ϕ1_, ϕ2_}] := 
 Module[{plot, pts, surf, bdy}, 
  plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
     Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
     Cos[ϕ]}, {θ, θ1, θ2}, {ϕ,  ϕ1, ϕ2},
  Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Black];
  pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[p_, ___] :> p, Infinity];
  surf = First@Cases[plot, Polygon[p_] :> p, Infinity];
  bdy = First@Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
  GraphicsComplex[
   Join[r1*pts, r2*pts], {EdgeForm[], Polygon[surf], 
    Polygon[Reverse /@ surf + Length@pts], 
    Polygon[Join[#, Reverse@# + Length@pts], 
       VertexNormals -> 
        Cross[Subtract @@ pts[[#]], pts[[First@#]]]] & /@ 
     Partition[bdy, 2, 1, 1]}, VertexNormals -> Join[-pts, pts]]]

Graphics3D[sphericalSegment[{1, 2}, {0, Pi/2}, {0, Pi/2}]]
```

[image]